# sdram banks configuration in uboot

Tags: memory, config, clock, u-boot, bank

I had made uclinux(uboot+kernel+romfs) for my disco board for (stm32f429).
Now I have a custom board which uses different bank (bank1 instead of bank2 in disco board) I tried to configure u-boot according to new board but I have an odd problem:
when I use the old u-boot without any changes, the boot loader can see kernel image but it has a HARD FAULT ERROR when it extracts the kernel image to SDRAM,and this is natural!
BUT when I configure uboot according to new board structure even uboot doesnt load and I see nothing in serial console!
could you please help me about it, it is more than two months Im trying to solve it!!!